# Is there a general word for performing music?

Tags: single-word-requests, music

If someone is performing music with an instrument, I'd say that they're *playing* the instrument.

If someone is performing music with their voice, I'd say that they're *singing*.

Is there a word that combines both of these connotations?

"In the band, there are pianists, drummers, flautists, and singers; they _____ together."

I wouldn't use *perform* in this context, because they're not performing in front of an audience. *Practice* also doesn't have the right connotation, and *playing* to me connotes strictly playing an instrument and wouldn't be used in the context of singing. *Jamming* is a relevant word, but to me connotes only certain types of musical styles. Is there a single word that would encapsulate both *singing* and *playing an instrument*?

Comment: Are they jamming? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jamming

Comment: "Playing" is commonly said about groups that have both instruments and vocals. @OrbitalAussie - "jamming" applies sometimes, but definitely not always.

Comment: @nnnnnn.  Yes, that’s why I used a question.

Comment: @Orbital Possibly. I’d rather a word a bit broader than that; I wouldn’t call playing classical music _jamming_, for instance.

Comment: You could jam on a classical motif, but no, the word doesn't really apply to most classical music.

Comment: If there's not a single word for it, you could just use "make music". That's shorter than a lot of single words.

Comment: When I used to play flute before an audience—any audience—I was *performing*; when I played outside of that context I was either *rehearsing* (with other musicians) or *practicing* (by myself). End of story.

Comment: What about 'rendition'?

Comment: @RamPillai rendition is a noun.  The question seeks a verb.

Comment: @phoog. This link says, rendition can be used also as a verb: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/rendition.html

Comment: @RamPillai that is correct, but the sense in which *rendition* may be used as a verb has nothing to do with music.  The verb that is related to the musical sense of *rendition* is *render,* but that doesn't work in the desired context either.

Comment: @RamPillai in the sentence you quote, the word *rendition* is used as a noun, as part of the noun phrase "a powerful rendition."  The verb is *ended.*

Comment: Yeah, I deleted that comment.